# FrameLayout doesn't fit its space

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragment

I am working for the first time with NavigationBar widget and I cannot set the FrameLayout not to go behind the NavigationBar.
I've tried really everything: to set both in a RelativeLayout (NavigationBar disappears) , every setting I've found here around StackOverflow but I didn't succeed.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.myActivity"
    android:background="@color/background_activities">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_NavigationBar"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope someone will help me to figure out where I made the mistake.
Thank you very much

**EDIT**
Now the navigation bar started to change dimension while clicked (it looks like the whole layout is "renderized" again) and now it get stucks in such a position 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, set the frame layout constraints to clip completly to the parent, except the bottom to clip to the navigation's top, then set the height and width to 0dp so it can grow according to the constraints:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.myActivity"
    android:background="@color/background_activities">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_NavigationBar"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Using your suggestion it works but now NavigationBar started to "change height" while clicked, I updated the first psot with the picture. Can you help me again please?

Comment: I don't see the picture :/

Comment: Try changing the height of the navigation to ``android:layout_height="wrap_content"``